# opcua python set_node from client BadTypeMismatch

Tags: python, automation, client-server, plc, opc-ua

I have a problem with setting a value to a node in opcua from a python client. Infact I get an error when I use set_node(intValue) I obtain a Bad type mismatch.
The code is:

```
time.sleep(1)
nodo = client.get_node("ns=1;i=68") 
nodo.set_value(0)
time.sleep(1)
nodo = client.get_node("ns=1;i=68")  
nodo.set_value(1)
```

And the error that I obtain is:
opcua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadTypeMismatch: "The value supplied supplied for the attribute is not the same type as the attribute"s value." (BadTypeMismatch)

Answer (score 3):

You must match the correct ua type.
To find the correct type you can use UAExpert, another test client or read the documentation of the server.

Possible types are

- ua.UInt32
- ua.Int32
- ua.Int16
- ua.UInt16
- ua.UInt64
- ua.Int64
- ua.Byte (unsigned 8bit)
- ua.SByte (signed 8bit)
- ...

For example for UInt32:

```
nodo.set_value(ua.UInt32(1))
```